# Get query rule name by GUID on the client

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, search, search-results, jsom

I'm using JSOM to iterate through search results on SharePoint 2013 search center.
There is a top level object `ResultTableCollection` which contains one or more `QueryGroup` objects, which, in turn, contain search results.
I noticed that every `QueryGroup` object contains a property named `QueryRuleId` corresponding to a `GUID` of query rule responsible for that particular block of search results.

Is there a way to get a display name of that query rule?

Any client side solution (JSOM, REST) is acceptable if it doesn't require admin rights. Ideally it should work in SharePoint Online as well.